# Does a Geologist get their gold if they're locked up?

Tags: saboteur-2

At the end of a game I just played, there were 5 crystals on the table, and the geologist was locked up.

Everyone else in the group said the geologist didn't get the gold, but nowhere in the rules did it say they didn't get their gold when locked up at the end of the game.

What is the real rule? Does the geologist get their gold?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer lies in the description of the Trapped card (which is used to lock someone up). This comes from the [official rules of Saboteur2](http://boardgamegeek.com/file/download/75t5b34xrr/Saboteur_2.pdf):

> Play this card face-up in front of another player of your choice. This
>   player is trapped and cannot play any more path cards. If a player is
>   trapped when the round ends, they don‘t get counted as one of the
>   winners and don‘t get a cut of the treasure

The Trapped card does not specify this status only applying to certain roles. So if a Geologist is trapped, that player would not get their gold.

I also found a [post](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9828315#9828315) on a BGG forum for Saboteur 2 from Frederic Moyersoen, the game designer who states that a Trapped Geologist gets no treasure.

Comment: But a geologist cannot be a winner. Their goal is only to get crystals and get the gold from the crystals. I figured that the rules on the trapped card were talking about people who actually get treasure by getting to the end or the sabotuer winning at the end. Both would be winners but the geologist is not a winner or a loser ever.

Comment: Added a link to forum post from the game designer.

Comment: @madelinemoore " When the treasure is split, a Geologist gets as many Gold Pieces as there are crystals visible in the maze of tunnels.". They're not winners or losers, but their gold is treated as part of the split.